# Protecting CGI scripts from outter call

Tags: apache, security, cgi

I have written a Python CGI script that accepts JSON input and returns JSON output. The script is hosted on an Apache web server, and it communicates with a PHP/HTML/JavaScript application.

I am concerned that someone may be able to access my CGI script directly, bypassing my application. For example, a malicious user could create a custom HTML/AJAX file that interacts with my CGI script by spoofing the HTTP_REFERER variable.

My question is:
Is there a way to configure Apache to allow my CGI script to be accessed only from my own website's root directory, and prevent unauthorized access from other sources?

I searched a lot on internet but the fact that I could not find a solution may mean that there is none.
I had some ideas with passwords, or reusing the session from php, but I am a bit confused about this.